# hide bootstrap dropdown with media query

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates, bootstrap-5

I have a bootstrap dropdown that is only visible when the screen is a certain width. My issue is that when I resize the screen to hide the dropdown button, the previously clicked/opened dropdown menu remains open.

Is there a way to close the dropdown or get rid of the show class for the menu based on a media query? I've seen answers to similar questions, but none that helped me.

What CSS can I add to close the dropdown menu? As of now it stays open until unfocused, but I'd like it to close kind of like this sites dropdown.

```css
.sm-screen-dropdown-menu {
  top: 48px !important;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) 0px 10px 36px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) 0px 0px 0px 1px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 200px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .hide-sidebar {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .sm-screen-dropdown {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .sm-screen-dropdown:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1sCRPdkRXhBV2PBLUdRb4tMg1w2YPf37qatUFeS7zlBy7jJI8Lf4VHwWfZZfpXtYSLy85pkm9GaYVYMfw5BC1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="dropdown center">
  <div class="sm-screen-dropdown" dropdown-toggle type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-bars menu-icon"></i>
  </div>
  
  <ul class="dropdown-menu sm-screen-dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <li>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <div class="dropdown-divider no-margin"></div>
    <div class="ms-2">
      <li>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'home' %}">Groups</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'taglist' %}">Tags</a>
      </li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Your list markup is invalid. A div is not an allowed child element.

Comment: as of now it works tho

Comment: "Works" is a poor standard. Invalid HTML is invalid HTML.

Comment: I'm saying what's the issue that's happening

Comment: either way i hear you and i fixed it by having two uls, but just wondering what's the issue with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not running your code in any kind of snippet, which makes it difficult to get the full picture. However, I threw this together to show you how to hide/display elements based on media query in JS, not in CSS.

**Run the snippet in full page, inspect and bring down the viewport width and you'll see the circle disappear when the viewport is less than 576px**

You can also check out this **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/r3hab/pen/zYWXvdL)**

```js
const smallDevice = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 576px)");
let circle = document.querySelector(".shape.circle");

smallDevice.addListener(handleDeviceChange);

function handleDeviceChange(e) {
  if (e.matches) circle.style.display = 'block';
  else circle.style.display = 'none';
}

//run it initially
handleDeviceChange(smallDevice);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.shape {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.shape + .shape {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
.shape.box {
  background: blue;
}
.shape.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape box"></div>
<div class="shape circle" style="display: none;"></div>
```